# Drupal 7: Core forum discussion with comment on front page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, forum, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I am using core forum in drupal 7. I want to see forum question with comment on front page and  is there is any option to put like button in comment box or any module like facebook comment in drupal. Please give me the some idea. thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve can be configured into a view. About the like button and a facebook comment check out [this link](https://drupal.org/project/facebook_comments_box). There are tons of facebook modules. You just need to search them!

Comment: @Mr.Goose my first question is how to bring the discussion forum question and comment on front page of my site in drupal 7.

Comment: @Mr.Goose I don't want to connect my comments to Facebook account. I need Facebook comment functionality. i.e. in comment box like button as well as counting the like of the comment(i.e. 5 people like that comment it is displaying inside the comment box).